# Does cucumber scan all steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does cucumber scan all step definitions?

I have a user_steps and a folder with all my user features.

It seems I need many of the 'I am loggin in" and "I exist as a user" type steps.

How can I refactor these out so that all features can use these steps?

Answer (score 2):

All the step files are automatically loaded by cucumber. That's why all the tests are able to access the web_steps file. You can organize your steps files however you like, and each test will have access to them.

Comment: if I do this:  cucumber feature/some.feature then it doesn't seem to load the steps, but if I just do: cucumber it works fine. why?

Comment: Try doing: `rake cucumber FEATURE=feature/some.feature`